# Excel 2010 VBA change a cell value in a table during a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out or find the answer.

I need the proper line of code to change a cell value in a table while inside a For loop. I'm trying to change the cell in column 16 of the current row to a value of TRUE. I have a work-around, not included here because I don't want to use it, that uses a counter and about six lines of code. I believe this can be done with a single line.

My code is very simple:

```
For Each row In [Table2].Rows

    Memail = (row.Columns(1).Value)

    Mname = (row.Columns(2).Value)

    Maddress = (row.Columns(3).Value)

    'etc. etc. do some stuff' 

    (row.Columns(16).Value) = TRUE 'What is the proper syntax for this line?'

Next
```

I can't figure out the code to replace column 16 with TRUE for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from around that line of code; they are not needed.

```
row.Columns(16).value = TRUE
```